# How to bind List<object> dynamically to a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

i want to bind list to a datagrid dynamically, following code works for first time, if click add again it is not getting populated in the data grid.

[image: screenshot]

```
       private List<Item> PopulateItemList()
    {
        return itemLst;
    }
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.Item1 = txtItem.Text;
        itemLst.Add(item);
        grdItem.ItemsSource = PopulateItemList();

    }
    private List<Item> itemLst = new List<Item>();

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        itemLst.Clear(); 

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for a good screenshot and a code sample that contains exactly the relevant parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`.

`ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which will tell WPF when you add or remove items.

Comment: I was going to type a very similar response.

Comment: In addition : The `ObservableCollection<T>` notify for list change (Add, Remove, Move) but not for `T` change. You need `T` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Either you should use ObservableCollection as suggested by Slaks. Otherwise you have to set the datatgrid itemSource null first before populating it again to some other value.
But i would strongly suggest you to use ObservableCollection and you can set it to datagrid's ItemSource in the UserControl's constructor instead of setting it again.